# Add /Remove dynamically HTML element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I found [this great code](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/9/17/jQuery--Dynamically-Adding-Form-Elements) here the [Demo](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/pages/jquery_dynamicFormElements.cfm). I just need some change. I'd like

- one button by line to delete the current line
- a confirmation before delete

Could you help me ?

Thanks,

Update 1:
I'd like this 
[alt text http://imagik.fr/thumb/275405.jpeg](http://imagik.fr/thumb/275405.jpeg)

Comment: check the updated answer i.e check the link it contains code that you want

Comment: how would you like the `name` of the input? e.g. `name="name1"`,`name="name2"`.. etc.??

Comment: @Reigel the textbob a name like "input1" and the corresponding delete button "btnDelete1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vh3Js/)

## html

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
        <input type="button" class="btnDel" value="Delete" disabled="disabled" />
        <input type="text" name="input1" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
    </div>
</form>​
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var inputs = 1; 

    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        $('.btnDel:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
        var c = $('.clonedInput:first').clone(true);
            c.children(':text').attr('name','input'+ (++inputs) );
        $('.clonedInput:last').after(c);
    });

    $('.btnDel').click(function() {
        if (confirm('continue delete?')) {
            --inputs;
            $(this).closest('.clonedInput').remove();
            $('.btnDel').attr('disabled',($('.clonedInput').length  < 2));
        }
    });


});
```

resources

- [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)
- [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Comment: Yes, it's that :) A small remark when you put a text in the textbox (in the first one), and you do an "add" the text is cloned too. Sorry I'm not a UI guys :)

Comment: What is method fixNames() is doing in this script